# Flex How to split time between day?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I would like to calculate the duration of time that span between 2 days.

Example: Date: 1/1, Start at 11pm and the duration end for 3 hours.

I would like to break the 3 hour apart for both days like the following:

Date --- Duration

Jan 1st ----- 1 hour

Jan 2nd ----- 2 hours

How to split the 3 hours time frame from Jan 1st (1hr) and the next day Jan 2nd (2hrs)?

thanks.

further explanation:

Basically, On day Jan 1st at 11pm run for 3 hrs, so the 3 hrs will span from Jan 1st to Jan 2nd. Giving Jan 1st 1hr (as Jan 1st start at 11pm [at night]) and to Jan 2nd 2hrs [in the morning].

So how to split the hours between the 2 days in code?

Comment: I downvoted because the question is not clear at all. I had to read it like 5 times and I'm not quite sure I understood correctly. Please make your question clearer and I'll gladly remove my downvote. I might even be able to help you! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each day lasts 24 hours (no daylight savings) and that the Start is at whole hours (an integer from 0 to 23), and that the duration is also a whole number, and that the time span doesn't go beyond the second day:

```
hoursInFirstDay = (start + duration > 24) ? (24 - start) : duration;
hoursInSecondDay = duration - firstDay;
```

For minutes, you could do something similar:

```
minsInDay = 24 *60;

startMoment = 60 * startHour + startMinutes;
durationInMins = 60 * durationHours + durationMinutes;

timeInFirstDay = (startMoment + durationInMins > minsInDay) ? (minsInDay - startMoment) : durationInMins;
timeInSecondDay = durationInMins - timeInFirstDay

hoursInFirstDay = int(timeInFirstDay / 60)
minsInFirstDay = timeInFirstDay % 60

hoursInSecondDay = int(timeInSecondDay / 60)
minsInSecondDay = timeInSecondDay % 60
```

Comment: Do you mean the start can be at a non-zero minute? How about the duration? Is that always whole hours?

Comment: No not always whole hour, (Sorry not putting minute in early). What about duration is 3hrs and 45mins, the start time is at 11:45pm.

Comment: Use the code above, setting startHour = 23, startMinutes = 45, durationHours = 3, durationMinutes = 45. The return values would be the last four lines.

Comment: I just wanted to add that thiere is a DateUtils Library, which I have found very useful for stuff like this. http://flexdateutils.riaforge.org/